Magento 2 Product Details page is being timed out
in our magento store everything was fine. But recently we are facing product details page is being timed out.
CPU Usage is also getting high if we open that product details page. It is only happening for random products.
After some hour or so it fixes automatically.
PHP configuration was also high.
any idea why this happening?

Additional DB information request, please.
OS, Version?
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
H) php configuration .ini
I) complete query that is timing out
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE,
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,
ulimit -a       for list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
df -h  for Used - Free space by device,
df -i  for inode info by device,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Consider running this query:
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') DATA_Space,
CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space, create_time, table_rows, engine, create_options
from information_schema.TABLES
where TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') and Data_free > ( DATA_length * .1)
ORDER BY FLOOR ( FREE_Space ) DESC, FLOOR ( DATA_Space ) DESC, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
LIMIT 0,512
;
and post the first 10 lines of output.  OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl_name; each of the tables listed.
